# Override controller issue on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, overrides, controllers, register

I try to override `Vendor\Modulename\Controller\Account\CreatePost.php` controller.
I want to do some changes  in this function. but it's not working.
If i try to override the execute function from the same controller it's works, but for this function it's not working

Does anyone know why for this function it's not working?

```
namespace Namaspace\ModuleName\Controller\Account;

class CreatePost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost{   
    protected function getSuccessMessage()
    {
        if ($this->addressHelper->isVatValidationEnabled()) {
            if ($this->addressHelper->getTaxCalculationAddressType() == Address::TYPE_SHIPPING) {
                // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
                $message = __(
                    'If you are a registered VAT customer, please <a href="%1">click here</a> to enter your shipping address for proper VAT calculation.',
                    $this->urlModel->getUrl('customer/address/edit')
                );
                // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
            } else {
                // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
                $message = __(
                    'If you are a registered VAT customer, please <a href="%1">click here</a> to enter your billing address for proper VAT calculation.',
                    $this->urlModel->getUrl('customer/address/edit')
                );
                // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
            }
        } else {
            $message = __('GUGUGUG you for registering with %1.', $this->storeManager->getStore()->getFrontendName());
        }
        return $message;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `getSuccessMessage` method?

Comment: i am trying to add a script tag in the mesasge like this: $message = __('Thank you for registering with %1.', $this->storeManager->getStore()->getFrontendName())."<script>
    dataLayer.push({
     'events': {
      'event': 'register',
      'category': 'register',
      'action': 'account register',
      'label': '".$this->session->getCustomer()->getId()."'
     }
    });
   </script>";

Comment: I try to add a GTM script when an user register for the first time

Comment: You should update your question with what you want to do.

Comment: I made this on local, and it;s works there, but if i put this on server, dosen;t work

Comment: first  I want to overrite this funciton. it's enough for me

Comment: Did you remove `var/generation` folder and try again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53261/discussion-between-alin-lupoiu-and-khoa-truongdinh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code lines should work. Try to clear your Magento Cache and remove `var/generation` folder. Make sure you test all cases for customer registration, for example, with email confirmation and without it.

*vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php*

```
if ($confirmationStatus === AccountManagementInterface::ACCOUNT_CONFIRMATION_REQUIRED) {
   ......
} else {
   ......
}
```

Comment: Thnaks! it works!